# cuFFT R2C batch output size doesn't match input size

Tags: fft, cufft

I'm experimenting with the batch with *cuFFT*. But I don't think I'm getting the right output.

```
int NX = 16;    // size of the array
int BATCH = 16; // # of batch
```

I'm allocating two arrays on the GPU:

```
float *src;
cufftComplex *dst;
cudaMalloc((void**)&src, sizeof(float)*NX*BATCH);
cudaMalloc((void**)&dst, sizeof(cufftComplex)*NX*BATCH);
```

I'm initializing the source array with a simple kernel like this:

```
__global__ void initFloatArray(float *data, const int size) {
  const int i = (blockIdx.x * blockDim.x) + threadIdx.x;
  if (i < size) {
    data[i] = i % NX;
  }
}
```

so basically, each array has values to goes from 0 to 15. And I get this 16 times.

I create my plan like this:

```
cufftPlanMany(&plan, 1, &NX, nullptr, 1, NX, nullptr, 1, NX, CUFFT_R2C, BATCH);
```

and then I'm executing my plan:

```
cufftExecR2C(plan, src, dst);
```

Finally, I transfer the content of *dst* back to the host. But when I print out the values, I'm getting this:

```
 BATCH 0:
  <120, 0>.length = 120
  <-8, 40.2187>.length = 41.0066
  <-8, 19.3137>.length = 20.905
  <-8, 11.9728>.length = 14.3996
  <-8, 8>.length = 11.3137
  <-8, 5.34543>.length = 9.62152
  <-8, 3.31371>.length = 8.65914
  <-8, 1.5913>.length = 8.15673
  <-8, 0>.length = 8
  <120, 0>.length = 120
  <-8, 40.2187>.length = 41.0066
  <-8, 19.3137>.length = 20.905
  <-8, 11.9728>.length = 14.3996
  <-8, 8>.length = 11.3137
  <-8, 5.34543>.length = 9.62152
  <-8, 3.31371>.length = 8.65914
 BATCH 1:
  <-8, 1.5913>.length = 8.15673
  <-8, 0>.length = 8
  <120, 0>.length = 120
  <-8, 40.2187>.length = 41.0066
  <-8, 19.3137>.length = 20.905
  <-8, 11.9728>.length = 14.3996
  ...
```

I was expecting a repetitive output, but it's repeat every 9 numbers, instead of every 16 like it should.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is there something I'm not understanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DFT of a real-valued signal exhibit Hermitian symmetry (see [real-input DFT on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#The_real-input_DFT)). As a result, the full `N` complex output values of a `N`-point DFT can be constructed from only the first `N/2+1` output values (ie. the other outputs are redundant).

Correspondingly and as with many FFT implementations for real-valued inputs, cuFFT does not return the redundant upper portion of the spectrum (as indicated in section 2.4 of [cuFFT library user's guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/pdf/CUFFT_Library.pdf)). In your case with a 16-point FFT, you would thus get `16/2 + 1 = 9` non-redundant outputs. Those 9 values per FFT then get packed back-to-back in your final `dst` buffer (thus a new FFT result starts every 9 complex number).

Comment: just to be more precise, it's floor(N/2)+1 complex values. So for 15, you get 8 complexes.

Comment: @widgg I think you don't need this `floor` as it will return an integer any way.